# PHP Checkboxes in an array

Tags: php

When a form gets posted, I get some checkbox values like the below:

```
Array ( [chk0] => true ,
        [chk1] => true,
        [chk3] => true,
        [chk1002] => on,
        [chk1005] => on 
      )
```

Using PHP,How can I construct a JSON request like this by using the above variables?

```
        "data":
        [
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 0
            },
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 1002
            },
            {
                "checkboxval": true,
                "id": 1005
            }
        ]
```

Please note that my POST variables can have other form variables too, but all checkbox values will be named with the prefix "chk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
  $output[] = array(
    'checkboxval' => !!$v,
    'id' => preg_replace('!^chk!', '', $k),
  );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data' => $output));
```

Comment: How do I get all the posted checkboxes in $input here?

Comment: I guess I can use $_POST for $input.. However, $output[] array(...) seems to be syntactically wrong..

Comment: @Vincent: It looks like @cletus left out an equals sign. I added it in for him.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  $output[] = array(
    'checkboxval' => ($v=='on'? true : ($v=='off' ? false : !!$v)),
    'id' => preg_replace('!^chk!', '', $k),
  );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data' => $output));
```

Credits to cletus who provided the basis for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) php function. You'll have to massage your array a little to get the exact JSON format you're after.

Comment: I am not so much worried for the JSON format..I am interested in the logic for scanning through the dynamically generated checkbox values which have a prefix of chk.

Comment: @Vincent Have a look at @Cletus' answer.

Comment: @Vincent: I made a minor correction to @cletus' answer. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example...

```
$_POST["chk1"] = "Hello";
$_POST["chk2"] = "World";
$jsonArray = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
  if(preg_match("/chk/", $key)){
    $jsonArray[$key] = $val;
  }
}
$jsonArray = array("Data" => $jsonArray);
$json = json_encode($jsonArray);
echo "<pre>";
echo $json;
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs this:

```
{"Data":{"chk1":"Hello","chk2":"World"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but maybe something like this:

```
$json = '"data": [';
$first = true;
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v){
    if (preg_match('/^chk(\d+)$/', $k, $m)){
        if ($first) $first = false; else $json .= ", ";
        $json .= sprintf('{ "checkboxval" : %s, "id" : %s }', ($v && $v != "off") ? "true" : "false", $m[1]);
    }
}
$json .= ']';
```